# Integration of testlink with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, testlink

I have integrated Testlink with Jenkins,
Here is the config file in Jenkins,
[image]

When I tried executing the job in Jenkins I am getting the following error,
[image]

Note : I have tried by generating new developer key but no luck.
Someone please look into it and help me resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think your testlink url is wrong in this .

it should be something like http://localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php